# Need to log lost password change request

Tags: php, wordpress

im creating a plugin that would log whenever a user requests a new password by clicking on 'lost your password?' link in the wp-login.php page. The end goal is to save the timestamp of the request and associate it with the user_id of the person who lost the password and save it to the wp_usermeta table. I tried all the actions associated with the password request but im not having any luck. Below is everything I have tried so far:

```html
function login_save_pw_reset_date() {

  $pw_reset_time = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); 

  add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_pw_change', $pw_reset_time );
  add_user_meta( $_POST['user_login'], 'user_pw_change', $pw_reset_time );
  add_user_meta( $_REQUEST['login'], 'user_pw_change', $pw_reset_time );
  add_user_meta( get_userdata( $user_id ), 'user_pw_change', $pw_reset_time );
  add_user_meta( get_user_by( 'login', $user_login ), 'user_pw_change', $pw_reset_time );
  add_user_meta( $user->id, 'user_pw_change', $pw_reset_time );


}

add_action( 'password_reset', 'login_save_pw_reset_date', 10, 2 ); 
add_action( 'lostpassword_post', 'login_save_pw_reset_date', 10, 2 ); 
add_action( 'retrieve_password', 'login_save_pw_reset_date', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'after_password_reset', 'login_save_pw_reset_date', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'lost_password', 'login_save_pw_reset_date', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'lostpassword_post', 'login_save_pw_reset_date', 10, 1 );
```

I also tried to pass in $user_id as the parameter in the login_save_pw_reset_date() function. Any help would be appreciated, I am all out of ideas.

Comment: In which file does this code live? If it's a plugin, has the plugin been enabled? If it's part of a `functions.php`, is the theme enabled?

Comment: It is a custom plugin and yes the plugin has been enabled.

Comment: Is the function being run? Can you test to see if the function's code is being run with an `echo` of some sort?

Comment: Yep, the function is being run because I try to var_dump the $_POST and $_REQUEST objects in the hopes that they will return some info. In addition I have a test echo in place. Ran password reset tests with the test echos and with them commented out.